# How to install window version of visual studio 2019 on mac using docker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, web, window

I am new user of mac . I was learning asp.net and implementing on visual studio 2019 window version. Now I switched on mac . And here its asp.net core but i want windows version of asp.net . can get window like visual studio through docker on mac ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Visual Studio is a Windows only product. You always have the option of running Visual Studio in something like [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/pd/windows-on-mac/) you also have some native Mac options:

- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/): This is a lightweight IDE that's really popular and used by a lot of people. It's cross platform and runs on Windows, Mac and Linux. I would definitely recommend checking this out.
- [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/): This is a more fully featured IDE. As you can see in the comparison on the VS for Mac site, it allows you to develop for web, desktop, mobile and more.
- [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/): A very powerful IDE, not developed by Microsoft but by JetBrains focused on .NET development fully cross platform and loved by many.

I would encourage you to explore them all and see for yourself what you like. I see myself using a combination of tools (mostly Visual Studio, Code and Rider) and switch between them during my day.